# Why are we being tested?

Tags: adam-and-eve, akhirah

I have always been told the story of Adam (AS) and how he sinned in Jannah and was sent down to Earth. However, we were not created at the time and had not sinned. So why do all of mankind have to be tested because of two people's mistake?

Also, I have recently come across a Hadith which states that Allah asked all of his creation if they are ready to be tested. However the mountains (rocks) feared the big test but Humans were foolish and said they are ready to be tested.

I don't see how these two are linked. Are we being tested because Adam and Hawa (Eve)(Peace be upon them) ate what was forbidden for them or are we being tested because we accepted the 'challenge'?

Comment: `because of two people's mistake`, please correct your language, and its not a mistake, he just slipped across his promise

Answer (score 2):

Initially you’d better pay attention to the verse below regarding the goal of creation.

> وَمَا خَلَقْتُ الْجِنَّ وَالْإِنسَ إِلَّا لِيَعْبُدُونِ  ﴿٥٦ /  And I did
>   not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me. (56)
>
> http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/51:56

So in accordance with the above-mentioned verse, the target of the creation is related to worshiping. Of course this is true that Adam… , but seemingly it is counted as a reason or excuse which could be led to creating the humans to come to the world to be tested. Actually you inquired a very significant question which its response would be too large and it needs many discussions. But in order to answer your inquiry (from another aspect) I can say that in fact Allah completely knows us and actually he doesn’t need to test us, but in truth he would test us for some reasons such as:

- worshiping of Allah
- in order to bringing up the talents of humans
- to show us who we are by doing our practices (since for instance if
  he would take us to the heaven directly, then we would be objector
  that why he didn’t give us any opportunity to show ourselves…

And some other items.

**Actually one of the most significant reason could be related to test us. So by paying attention to the verse below which declares:**

> انا خلقنا الانسان من نطفه امشاج تبتليه فجعلناه سميعا بصيرا انا هدينا
>   السبيل اما شاكرا و اما كفورا;
>
> Indeed, we created man from a sperm-drop mixture that We may try him;
>   and We made him hearing and seeing. (2) Indeed, We guided him to the
>   way, be he grateful or be he ungrateful. (3) (76:2,3)

Thus these verses indicate that Allah would test us. Of course the main issue is that Allah know us perfectly, but the point is that he intends to show us that who we are, (for the doomsday…). Of course I haven’t heard the issue which you mentioned that Allah asked all of his creation if they are ready to be tested. So I wish you present this tradition by its source to consider its authenticity. And eventually this is true that you mentioned the issue Adam and Havva(Eve), but as I declared, it seems that the issue of Adam and Eve is a reason or an excuse which led to …, otherwise the main goal of the creation is related to other issues such as worshipping of Allah and testing of us and perhaps some other items.

---

**References:**

- [tanzil.net 1](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/51:56)
- [tanzil.net 2](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/76:2)

Comment: I absolutely agree however, why are we being tested? Couldn't we just worship Allah in Jannah?

Comment: it that case we would be relatively like Malaekah. I assume a significant cause is attaining to the perfection (of our talents).

Comment: On the other hand, e.g : You know the value of the money that you yourself have obtained in compare with the money that other give you as a gift. Since you know you have suffered (hard work) to gain it, then ... and many other reason.

Answer (score 2):

Please read carefully from [Surat Al-Baqarah 2/30](http://quran.com/2/30) to [Surat Al-Baqarah 2/39](http://quran.com/2/39). Then watch this video: [by Prof. Jeffrey Lang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1Wh8J6xy3E). It is a long video (1.5 hour), but it is very enlightening, please watch it until the end.

As a short answer, we are not on Earth because of the sin of Adam and Eve (peace be upon them). We are here to be tested individually. Mankind is created for eternal life, but our bodies are created for this world at the beginning. The forbidden fruit issue was the first opposition of mankind against Allah, it was the first use of free will. It was the signal to indicate the beginning of Test on Earth.

The test is being held to differentiate people, to decide who will go to Heaven, and who will go to Hell. As I said, mankind is created for eternal life, not for eternal life in Heaven. You have to earn that.

Answer (score 1):

This is my personal point of view:

First of all you can find a general answer of your question in 51:56

**And I did not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me.**

Now let's have a look at 46:14

**Those are the companions of Paradise, abiding eternally therein as reward for what they used to do.**

Here, you will notice that Allah promises an immortal life in paradise.
So, how is it possible that Allah forces Adam to leave jannah although Allah promises an
eternal life??

To answer this question you can now read 64:9

**...And whoever believes in Allah and does righteousness - He will remove from him his misdeeds 
and admit him to gardens beneath which rivers flow, wherein they will abide forever...**

In this ayah the Arabic word jannah is translated as *garden* instead of paradise.
Indeed, one of the meaning of jannah is garden and therefore I personally do not believe that
Adam had been in paradise before he was tested by Allah. 
Instead, it is more than likely that he already had stayed on earth in a beautiful oasis or something like that *(Garden)*. After his sin he had to leave the *jannah or garden*.
It seems that Allah even has tested Adam on earth as like any other of us... This rule allows of no exceptions!

And I personally don't believe that Adam was the first human being on earth; 
There are no leads on the first human being of Adam in the Koran.
The Koran tells us that he was the **FIRST** prophet but he was **NOT the first human being!**
For this reason, I think that other human beings besides Adam had existed, but Adam was the first protoype of mankind
who was able to differentiate between good and evil, the wrong way the right way (see 2:30).

In respect of the points I have mentioned I think that the story of Adam wants to show us
that the whole mankind after Adam will be tested by doing good things and by working for a better world (read Sura Asr).

Adam did a mistake, but this does not mean that we are guilty for his behaviour (53:38)

**Namely, that no bearer of burdens can bear the burden of another;**

Comment: If Adam was not the first Human being created then why does the Qur'an mention how Allah created Adam first them Hawa from his rib. Also because there were no other humans, their children had to marry each other.

Comment: ok, I didn't found any ayah that Adams children did married each other and that her name was Hawa? Maybe you can help me? I think this is  biologically impossible and even Allah forbids marrying with relatives (4:176). The creation of mankind is explained in (22:5). You can further read 19:58 where Allah says that we are the descendants of Adam and not the desecendents of the first human

Comment: @kadesh you must read Surah 15 verse 26 to 31.
"And We did certainly create man out of clay from an altered black mud."
"And the jinn We created before from scorching fire."
So Before human beings there is jIN'S.
"And [mention, O Muhammad], when your Lord said to the angels, "I will create a human being out of clay from an altered black mud."
"And when I have proportioned him and breathed into him of My [created] soul, then fall down to him in prostration."
SO that was Adam as Quran said the first human being.

Comment: @messi1897: yes, each human being is created in the same way as it is explained in 15:26-31. But the explanation is regarding more to the difference between jinn and human beiings. But in 2:30 Allah further says, that he will create a "successive authority.", a caliph. Of course you're right, but you have to keep in mind that Allah wants to give us the message that adam was the first human being **AND** who was the first authority or first prohpet on earth.

Comment: @messi1987: I'm really sorry for my poor explanation. What I meant was that Adam was the first human being who became the first prophet on earth

Comment: @Kadesh as Adam was the first human being, then later his children appeared. There were no other humans on earth for his children to marry and so had to marry each other. The children were born in pairs (one boy and one girl) so they married each other's 'womb' brother and sister not their own 'womb' brother or sister.

Comment: @Zohal ok, can you give me some references of your thesis?

Comment: @kadesh I had read it somewhere else but cant remember but it is also here http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OW_wl7enoZY

Answer (score 0):

If Allah had so willed he could have easily created us as infallible droids that never make mistakes and worship him perfectly.  There would have been no challenge then to get closer to Allah, as everyone would be static and perfect in their relationship to Allah.

Can you be a great swimmer if you never enter the water?  Can an athlete gain strength without working his muscles?  Can you learn mathematics without trying to solve equations?  Mistakes are par for the course in any endeavor.  To make progress in any endeavor we pass incremental benchmarks, challenges, or open or implied "tests". By making mistakes, then learning from them and repenting for them, we build our spiritual muscle and get closer to Allah and piety.

Adam and Eve were erring humans just like us.  Their mistakes belong to them, to us our own. Everyone's account is separate.  Sheytan's purpose is to test us.  As long as we have faith, we can realize our mistakes and failings and ask Allah to forgive us through his infinite mercy.  The unfaithful, either being ignorant (Jahal) or rejecting faith (kufur), are not even aware that they are being tested or making mistakes.

Answer (score -2):

I think this verse can provide an answer to your question:

> And [mention] when your Lord took from the children of Adam - from their loins - their descendants and made them testify of themselves, [saying to them], "Am I not your Lord?" They said, "Yes, we have testified." [This] - lest you should say on the day of Resurrection, "Indeed, we were of this unaware." ([Surat Al-'A`rāf 7/172](http://quran.com/7/172))

EDIT:I'm sorry for the short answer,  I must have elaborated on it a bit.

I quote a passage from previously answered question similar to above one.

We have been Muslims since Qalu Bala.

> Allah created the spirits of all people before He created the world and the 
>   beings in it. He brought them together in a place called the realm of spirits.
>   Then, he brought all of them to his presence and asked them:
>
> – Alastu birabbikum= Am I not your Lord?
>
> The spirits answered:
>
> – Qalu:Bala=They said:Yes you are.
>
> They also said, “Thee do we worship, and  Thine aid we seek.”
>
> The time when the conversation above took place is called Qalu Bala.

For more info check out [this link](http://www.questionsonislam.com/article/what-does-qalu-bala-mean-and-when-have-we-been-muslims)

Answer (score -2):

I don't know exactly what you're asking about. But you said Allah asked all of his creation if they are ready to be tested. However the mountains (rocks) feared the big test but Humans were *foolish* and said they are ready to be tested.

I think it's some kind of misunderstanding or mistranslation foolish is not an attribute for all human beings it's for who didn't worship god and who are the failures.